# Проблема с циклом и указателем

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, память

Написал функцию копирования массива, которая по не понятным причинам работает неправильно. Если вместо указательной арифметики использовать индексы, то всё работает. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема

```cpp
template <typename T>
void copy_array(T *old_data, T *copy_data)
{

    int size_old_data = sizeof old_data / sizeof old_data[0];
    copy_data = new T [size_old_data] {};
    for (T *i1 = old_data, *i2 = copy_data; i1 != i1+size_old_data; ++i1, ++i2)
    {
        *i2 = *i1;
    }

}
```

В следующем примере код работает некорректно  и возвращает следующее сообщение: *Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)*

```cpp
int main() {
    struct Circle *my_data = nullptr;
    int test_data[2] {1,2};
    int *copy_data_2 = nullptr;
    copy_array(test_data, copy_data_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу несколько ошибок.

```
void copy_array(T *old_data, T *copy_data)
```

Передача по значению, т.е. значение указателя копируется в локальную переменную. Результат: при передаче указателя

```
int *copy_data_2 = nullptr;
copy_array(test_data, copy_data_2);
```

исходный указатель после вызова функции так и останется `nullptr`.

Далее:

```
int size_old_data = sizeof old_data / sizeof old_data[0];
```

Сами же написали: `void copy_array(T *old_data, ...` — т.е. `old_data` просто указатель. Так что получаете размер указателя в байтах, деленный на размер элемента... При неудачном сочетании может вообще быть ноль.

И еще, забавная проверка:

```
i1 != i1+size_old_data;
```

Т.е., вычитая слева и справа по `i1`, получаем проверку

```
0 != size_old_data;
```

Что, как правило, выполняется, так что получается очень бесконечный цикл...

Достаточно?

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо. Теперь работает